# Terraform strategy for handling multiple deployments

Tags: azure-devops, terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I'm trying to put together a Terraform deployment pipeline in Azure DevOps. I've found some blogs that give examples of various approaches, but some of the implementations I've seen don't make much sense to me.

Example 1.

One blog describes an ADO pipeline approach that runs `terraform plan` in one pipeline, stores the plan in a pipeline artifact, and then runs `terraform apply` in a deployment pipeline using the plan file retrieved from the artifacts. This confuses me because it's not storing the tfstate file anywhere. If after runnng an initial deployment I were to modify my Terraform configuration to add or modify various resources, how would rerunning this pipeline handle that?

I've read most of the Terraform documentation now and I haven't come across anything yet that suggests the tfstate is optional.

Example 2.

Another blog described a strategy in which an Azure Blob Container was configured as the backend for a Terraform deployment. Using this approach I could see how this would work for a single deployment of an application and how updating the Terraform configuration would update the deployment. But it was statically configurated with a single Blob Container, so how could that possibly handle multiple deployments of the same app?

I've never encountered the case where an app has a single deployment, at the very least any app I've ever worked on has Dev, Staging and Production environments and each of these is an independent standalone deployment.

I would expect a decent Terraform based pipeline to be told what environment to deploy to, and to then either update that environment if it already exists, or create the new environment if it doesn't, and it seems to me that in the case where a new environment is being created a new storage container would be required for the tfstate.

--

So on the one hand the strategies I've seen seem naive and incomplete, but on the other hand I don't fully understand all the concepts involved and these people seemed to think they understood Terraform well enough to write a blog about it.

So to recap my key questions:

Is a deployment strategy that doesn't use tfstate a viable approach?

Assuming tfstate is required to update a deployment then don't I need to store tfstate for each deployment?

Does anyone know of any documentation that describes a decent strategy for using Terraform to create and update multiple deployments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Another blog described a strategy in which an Azure Blob Container was configured as the backend for a Terraform deployment. Using this approach I could see how this would work for a single deployment of an application and how updating the Terraform configuration would update the deployment. But it was statically configurated with a single Blob Container, so how could that possibly handle multiple deployments of the same app?
>
> I've never encountered the case where an app has a single deployment, at the very least any app I've ever worked on has Dev, Staging and Production environments and each of these is an independent standalone deployment.

This is the way to go, but what you are missing is the [Terraform Workspaces](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/cli/workspaces) feature. Using Terraform Workspaces you will have a single backend configuration, but inside that Blob Container Terraform will create multiple state files, one for each workspace that you create.

---

> Is a deployment strategy that doesn't use tfstate a viable approach?

No, that totally breaks how Terraform works. It would think it was deploying to a new, empty environment each time you ran it, and it would try recreating things that already exist. You absolutely have to maintain the state file between deployments/updates in order for Terraform to work correctly.

Answer (score 1):

I don't recommend discarding the state file, else you lose some of the major benefits of using terraform. e.g you won't be able to use terraform destroy, or do updates. For further info on the state file see the Hashicorp doc [Purpose of Terraform State](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/state/purpose).

What you might want to do is have a `tfbackend` file for each of your deployments AKA environments e.g DEV, TEST, PROD. As per the [Backend docs](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/settings/backends/configuration).

For example, in your Terraform module you could have

```bash
main.tf
variables.tf
dev.tfbackend
prod.tfbackend
```

An example `tfbackend` file looks like:

```
terraform {
  backend "remote" {
    organization = "example_corp"

    workspaces {
      name = "my-app-prod"
    }
  }
}
```

Initialize your module with `terraform init -backend-config=dev.tfbackend` (for DEV). Then any time you run your pipeline against a particular environment you should pass a flag to the respective `tfbackend` file again. e.g `terraform plan -backend-config=dev.tfbackend -out banana`